# PushNotification plugin is not installed

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I want to implement ionic push notifications like iv'e done a few times in the past.

Here's the docs:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/

Installed everything, but it keeps saying PushNotification plugin is not installed.

This is my package.json:

[image]

Clearly there is a peer of @ionic-native/push installed.

However if I run

`npm install --save @ionic-native/push`

I get a lot of unmet peer deps that are also already installed?

[image]

I already tried a timeout before running the push code but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading my Cordova and Node (to 8.x.x!) installations helped resolve the issue.

- cordova (Cordova CLI)  : 7.1.0
- Cordova Platforms      : android 6.3.0 ios 4.5.4
- Ionic Framework        : ionic-angular 3.6.1
- ionic (Ionic CLI)      : 3.19.0
- Node                   : v8.9.1 --> Version 9.x.x gave other errors
- npm                    : 5.2.0

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You must have cordova-cli at 7.1.0 at least (plugin phonegap push requirements)